# Filter with function parameter ignores return value

Tags: angularjs

I have this bit of markup:

```
<option
   ng-repeat="item in data track by item.id | filter:dropdownFilter($index,item)">
</option>
```

And this part inside the controller:

```
$scope.dropdownFilter=function(index,item)
{
   console.log(index,item);//Works, outputs each item and its index
   return false;//Doesn't work, all options are available
}
```

Notes:

- I know I can write a custom filter, as in module(...).filter(...).
- I know how to use `ngOptions`, but let's focus on `ngRepeat` for now.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the documentation on ngRepeat.

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngRepeat

Relevant snippit:

> For example: item in items | filter:searchText track by item.id is a
>   pattern that might be used to apply a filter to items in conjunction
>   with a tracking expression.

I think you should try changing your ng-repeat statement to this:

```
<option
   ng-repeat="item in data | filter:dropdownFilter($index,item) track by item.id">
</option>
```

Comment: Thanks, Craig. That was it.